# useContext gives App.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I am using an Auth Context Provider in my App, which is initialised in this file:

`authState.js`

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

const initialState = {
  user: null,
};

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthStateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuthContext = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

This context is then imported in App.js for getting the user auth details:

`App.js`

```
...
...
import { useAuthContext } from './context/auth/authState';
...
...
const [{ user }, authDispatch] = useAuthContext();
```

I get the error at `const [{ user }, authDispatch] = useAuthContext();` line.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but according to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) the `useContext` returns only a single value.

That is why you can not destruct it with your current logic, the `[{ user }, authDispatch] = useAuthContext();`. This is just a quick idea, with the details you provided. :)

Edit: check what you actually pass in with the `useAuthContext`, maybe that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for responding , but we can actually destructure it this way , cuz I export [{state, dispatch}].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this, so I console logged `useAuthContext()` on @vazsonyidl suggestion and received undefined. So the `[state,dispatch]` were not known to `<App/>` component. All I did was to wrap my `App` component within `<AuthStateProvider></AuthStateProvider>` and it was resolved. Thanks for the suggestion @vazsonyidl.